# Trouble finding particular page that exists in the menu

Tags: articles, content

The page in question - the Contact Page - does not appear in Articles. It does appear in my Main Menu, but there is still no way to edit its content.

The link the menu item is pointing to is:

```
index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id=1
```

There is a Contacts component but this appears empty and unused.

There is a Contact Form in Modules which correlates to the form on the contact page but again there is no way to edit the text content that appears on the actual contact page.

K2 is installed, but the contact page does not appear amongst the items listed there.

This has got me really scratching my head. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you edit the menu item you'll be presented with the option to select a different contact. If you aren't using contacts anyway, simply unpublish or delete the menu item.

Answer (score 7):

The link you're referencing is telling Joomla to use the Contacts component to display information about the contact in the database with id #1...so...you need to log into the administrator, and go to the Contacts component.

Once there, there *should* be a contact with ID #1, but by the sounds of it, that record may be deleted, unpublished, or possibly trashed - you'll need to investigate on your end to determine that.

If the record is there, you need to insure that it is published for that original link to work.  If that record is NOT there, you'll need to add a new one.  That will create record in the database with a *different* id#, so you will then need to go to the Menu Manager, locate the menu item, and change the Contact to be displayed to the one you just added. (*an afterthought...if record #1 was never there to begin with, adding it in the Contact Component may create the record that the module is expecting to be there to begin with*)

Or, if its a module that isn't displaying the info, you need to go to the Module manager to change the Contact currently specified (#1), to the one you just added.

And finally, when in the Component Manager, top right, you can click on Options and make some changes about how the Contact component behaves.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but although there is a contact with id#1 it has different form fields then the form on the front end. I still cannot see any way to change the text information next to the form. There are no modules  for these areas either. Really weird